# One of my favourite things IS ...followed by a plural?

Tags: grammar

One of my students has written "one of my favourite things is the many cafes.."

Embarrassingly, I am just not sure if this is correct or not!
I know that cafes is plural but I have talked myself around because the favourite thing is actually 'the fact that there are cafes' and that fact is singular. Please help! :-)

Comment: In virtually all cases, the subject determines the verb for number purposes. Here, the subject has singular "one" as head, so the verb should be the singular "is". Singular subjects and plural predicative complements are commonplace, cf. "The only **thing** we need now is some new **curtains**" / "The major **asset** of the team is its world-class opening **bowlers**"

Comment: @BillJ - This should be an answer

Comment: 'One of my favourite things is the many cafes' sounds to me like it would be better recast as say 'A favourite occupation of mine is to visit one of the city's many fine cafes'. Or 'One of the things I like best about the city is the fact that it has so many wonderful cafes'. Grammaticality isn't everything.

Comment: I think what they wrote is OK. They're not referring to each cafe as a member of their favorite things, it's the single fact that there are many cafes. Or the set of many cafes -- a set is singular even though it contains plural elements.